# Установить скорость передачи USB

Tags: c++-cli

bResult возвращает false, может я не верно передаю структуру?

```
    SERIAL_BAUD_RATE s;
    s.BaudRate = BAUD_9600;
    ResetEvent(ConDevice);
    bool bResult = DeviceIoControl(ConDevice,  // запрошенное устройство
        IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE,  // выполняемая операция
        &s.BaudRate, sizeof(s), 
        NULL, 0,     // буфер вывода
        &ReturnLength,                 // # возвращено байтов
        (LPOVERLAPPED)Overlap);  // синхронизация ввода/вывода (I/O)
```